# Maven based example throws exception

Tags: openapi, spring-cloud-contract

I'm getting a very similar problem to some others who are trying to use the spring-cloud-contract-oa3 plugin and contracts in an openapi YAML spec.

I'm using maven with 2.1.2.0 of the plugin and 3.0.3 of SCC -

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.3</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <testFramework>JUNIT5</testFramework>
                    <baseClassForTests>com.bt.b2c.oa3cdc.contracts.BaseTestClass</baseClassForTests>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-oa3</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

What I'm a bit suspicious of is that the errors kind of imply the default parser is used (and hence will break). In the log below wouldn't we expect to see OpenApiContractConverter being used?

```
    [DEBUG] Parsed rootNode: {"openapi":"3.0.1", ..... }
    [ERROR] Unexpected error in reading contract file
    [ERROR] Cannot compare java.util.ArrayList with value '[null, null]' and java.lang.Integer with value '0'
    [WARNING] Error Processing yaml file. Skipping Contract Generation 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred while processing the file [E:\git\selfserve\oa3cdc\src\test\resources\contracts\incidents_openapi.yaml]
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.converter.YamlToContracts.convertFrom(YamlToContracts.java:94)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.converter.YamlContractConverter.isAccepted(YamlContractConverter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.file.ContractFileScanner.tryConvert(ContractFileScanner.java:320)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.file.ContractFileScanner.addContractToTestGeneration(ContractFileScanner.java:302)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.file.ContractFileScanner.appendRecursively(ContractFileScanner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.file.ContractFileScanner.findContractsRecursively(ContractFileScanner.java:237)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.TestGenerator.generateTestClasses(TestGenerator.java:131)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.TestGenerator.generate(TestGenerator.java:111)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.maven.verifier.GenerateTestsMojo.execute(GenerateTestsMojo.java:300)
```

Any ideas? I suspect I've done something dumb but I don't see it

Answer (score 0):

You are using Spring Cloud Contract in version 3.0.3 and the openapi plugin in versoin 2.1.2.0 that is incompatible with SCC 3.0.3. In my fork of the plugin at the `upgrade` branch I've upgraded the plugin to be compatible with SCC 3.0.x. To use it you should use jitpack.io in the following way

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <testFramework>JUNIT5</testFramework>
                <baseClassForTests>com.bt.b2c.oa3cdc.contracts.BaseTestClass</baseClassForTests>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Until a Spring Cloud Contract 3.0.x compatible version gets released -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.marcingrzejszczak</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-oa3</artifactId>
                    <version>upgrade-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>           
    </plugins>
</build>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Marcin, thanks for the update. That said I can't get the above to work, maven complains with: "Could not transfer artifact com.github.marcingrzejszczak:spring-cloud-contract-oa3:pom:spring-cloud-contract-3.0.x from/to jitpack.io (https://jitpack.io): Transfer failed for https://jitpack.io/com/github/marcingrzejszczak/spring-cloud-contract-oa3/spring-cloud-contract-3.0.x/spring-cloud-contract-oa3-spring-cloud-contract-3.0.x.pom"

Comment: Please try again - I can access this file https://jitpack.io/com/github/marcingrzejszczak/spring-cloud-contract-oa3/spring-cloud-contract-3.0.x/spring-cloud-contract-oa3-spring-cloud-contract-3.0.x.pom

Comment: Hi yes I can pull the POM file now (some proxy issue my end) but now I get complaint afterwards about the jar : `Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.github.marcingrzejszczak:spring-cloud-contract-oa3:jar:spring-cloud-contract-3.0.x in jitpack.io (https://jitpack.io)`

Comment: Ok I've updated the answer. Apparently you can't use my tag - you'll have to use the branch. So set the version to `upgrade-SNAPSHOT`. https://jitpack.io/#marcingrzejszczak/spring-cloud-contract-oa3/upgrade-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Marcin, I seem to have come full circle. I can see in ~/.m2 that I have pulled down the upgrade snapshot jar (g43e8cb9) ok. However when I run the convert goal I get exactly the same message as originally so. When running with -X I'd sort of expect a log message saying it chooses to use OpenApiContractConverter but I don't see that

Comment: Right looking at this again, I can indeed see that the OpenAPI converter is found by the spring factory and is in the list of 3 possible converters. Debugging the maven though it seems that when attempting via this.tryConvert(converter,file) is throwing IllegalStateException. I will try with another example oa3 yaml file